# Do PHP files with multiple extensions gets parsed?

Tags: php, security, backup

I have a habit of making file backups by adding the .bak extension (file.ext.bak).

Imagine if I have a config in PHP, config.php and I want to backup that file by adding the .bak extension, will the file get parsed or will you see the source code if a client accidentally end up at that url? Is it server dependent?

I've tried some tests on a MAMP server but it seems to be parsing

Comment: How about using version control instead of manual copies?

Comment: How is not using VC lazy? Just hitting commit and putting the files into the accessible directory saves so much time compared using FTP or similar mechanisms. And manual rename backups costs even more time.

Comment: But before you're hitting 'commit' you have to install, configure and understand the application you're using. Sorry man, but I asked whether it's safe or not. I did not ask if there are other ways to replace files.

Comment: Instead of asking SO,  you should test it what if someone said it was ok and it executes anyway?   By default if Apache doesn't recognize the first extension it will fall back on the next one.  So `test.php.crap` will execute as a php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the server configuration. It is a bad habit to keep those files accessible by browsers anyway, but should you want to, check your httpd.conf for these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

This will tell the webserver that .php files actually contain code to be executed.

- You could add the .bak file there (but it remains a bad habit).
- Another workaround would be to just rename the file to file.bak.ext
  instead).
- The best solution remains moving the files to somewhere where the
  browser can't access them, out of the document root and other
  mappings.

Comment: As I expected. Thanks for confirming and your good explaining.

Answer (score 3):

> will the file get parsed or will you see the source code if a client accidentally end up at that url?

Usually, you will see the source code because the `.bak` extension is not registered to be parsed with PHP. Needless to say, this is very dangerous!

> Is it server dependent?

Yes. It is possible to configure the server to parse those files, but it's not part of any default configuration I know.

The better solution is to do it the other way round: `filename.bak.php`